# Cox PH model HR - is it possible to measure against the general average?

Tags: r, survival, hazard, proportional-hazards

Reproducible example:

```
require(finalfit)
require(dplyr)


set.seed(42)

a <- c(32,291,545, 44,3,792,352, 20,615,169, 61,156, 88,863,255, 33,132,5,
       63,8,964,831, 55,133, 12, 54,261,867, 17, 12,699,233,251,446, 43,223, 
       374, 75, 34, 69,120, 84,134,8,806,8, 48, 86,211, 2436, 61, 81, 87, 12, 
       838, 34, 17,141, 44,155,128,6, 29, 16, 16, 34,130,430,325, 41, 28, 53, 
       86, 54,3,630, 93,699, 25,746,6, 46, 22, 60,395,402,151, 26, 38,125, 
       191, 49, 59,6, 34, 56,2, 96, 422, 45, 70)

b <- sample(c("A", "B", "C"), length(a), replace = T)

c <- sample(0:1, length(a), replace = T)

df <- data.frame(a, b, c)

dependent  <- "Surv(time = a, event = c)"
explanatory   <- "b"

df %>%
  coxphuni(dependent, explanatory) %>%
  finalfit::fit2df() -> coxphdf
```

The table coxphdf gives a HR for bB and bC, taking bA as a reference. Instead of this, would it be possible to measure hazard against the general average? I.e. calculate survival without regard to "b", and then saying that compared to this, belonging to "A" raises/lowers the risk by x, etc. In my real data it does not really make sense to make any of the factor levels reference, and I don't want to lose a category, if possible. If what I am trying to do is possible, how would I need to transform the data to achieve this?

Comment: There are 2 types of "general average" here. One is an average among the _individuals_ (presumably representing the underlying population and their distributions among the groups A, B, C), the other is the average among the groups. Those "averages" aren't necessarily the same. Which are you interested in?

Comment: Thank you for your response, EdM. I meant the average among the groups.

Comment: No because there's no concept of an intercept in a Cox model. There's no way to show three hazard ratios against a "general average" as would be the case with a linear model using an ANOVA contrast because the baseline hazard function is an ancillary parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never really "lose a category" in regression against a categorical predictor, you just have to get the comparisons that you want from the model results. In a Cox model it's best to work with the regression coefficients first, then convert to hazard ratios by exponentiating. The regression coefficient for the reference level ("A" here) is 0 in a Cox model.

For a comparison against the average among groups, you can find the average of the 3 regression coefficients (0 for "A" and the individual values found for for "B" and "C") and evaluate the differences of each coefficient against that average. For standard errors you would have to use the formula for the [variance of a weighted sum of correlated variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Weighted_sum_of_variables) along with the variance-covariance matrix of the model coefficient estimates.

Instead of doing this by hand, take advantage of the post-modeling tools provided by packages like [`emmeans`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=emmeans). You can then specify the comparisons/contrasts that you desire and display results in either the original coefficient scale or in the hazard-ratio scale. After you fit your data with the `coxph()` function, the "eff" contrast method in `emmeans` provides what you want in the hazard-ratio scale:

```
library(survival)
cox1 <- coxph(Surv(a,c)~b,data=df)
library(emmeans)
emmeans(cox1,eff~b,type="response")$contrasts
#  contrast ratio    SE  df null z.ratio p.value
#  A effect 1.071 0.207 Inf    1   0.357  0.7212
#  B effect 1.339 0.250 Inf    1   1.567  0.1834
#  C effect 0.697 0.163 Inf    1  -1.545  0.1834
# 
# P value adjustment: fdr method for 3 tests 
# Tests are performed on the log scale
```

If you remove the `type="response"` and the `$contrasts` from that function call, you can get a better idea of what's going on under the hood: in the "contrasts" you get comparisons of each of the original regression coefficients (the "emmeans") against their mean.

```
emmeans(cox1,eff~b)
# $emmeans
#  b emmean    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
#  A  0.000 0.000 Inf     0.000     0.000
#  B  0.223 0.299 Inf    -0.363     0.810
#  C -0.430 0.386 Inf    -1.187     0.327
# 
# Results are given on the log (not the response) scale. 
# Confidence level used: 0.95 
# 
# $contrasts
#  contrast estimate    SE  df z.ratio p.value
#  A effect   0.0689 0.193 Inf   0.357  0.7212
#  B effect   0.2922 0.186 Inf   1.567  0.1834
#  C effect  -0.3611 0.234 Inf  -1.545  0.1834
# 
# Results are given on the log (not the response) scale. 
# P value adjustment: fdr method for 3 tests
```

Comment: Thank you very much, EdM, hugely helpful, much appreciated!